# Why is ifup not running all of the if-pre-up.d scripts?

Tags: networking

```
$ ll /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/

total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 15 16:43 ./
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jan 14 21:29 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  344 Apr 28  2012 ethtool*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  158 Jan 14 22:01 iptablesload.sh*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3839 May  3  2012 wireless-tools*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32 Dec  4 13:00 wpasupplicant -> ../../wpa_supplicant/ifupdown.sh*

$ sudo ifup --all -v

run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/000resolvconf
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-autoipd
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-daemon
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ntpdate
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/openssh-server
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/upstart
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/wpasupplicant
```

Why is iptablesload.sh not being run? Is there some other location where a list of pre-up scripts is set?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had this same issue. From what I can tell, if you remove the trailing ".sh" this should work as expected.

```
sudo mv /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptablesload{.sh,}
```

Comment: Thank you! Think warranted a closer inspection of run-parts manpage. "If neither the --lsbsysinit option nor the --regex option is given then the names must consist entirely of ASCII upper-  and  lower-case  letters,  ASCII  digits,  ASCII underscores, and ASCII minus-hyphens." Seems that period is not part of that character set.

Comment: Didn't make the scripts run on Ubuntu 20 Server

Answer (score 5):

I can't get to work in ubuntu 20.4 either. script is called iptablesload residing in the if-pre-up.d directory.

I had to do

**apt install ifupdown**

that should solve on U 20.4, it did for me.

Comment: thank u very much!

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked for me